# How to change style of hyperlinks within PDF published from org-mode document?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf

I'm exporting (publishing) an org-mode document to PDF, and the results look great except for the hyperlinks. They look *terrible*.
[image: partial screenshot]

Hyperlinks to the Web look the same, only with a pale blue outline. How can I control the style of links in the exported PDF document? (I don't know LaTeX, but can make simple configuration changes in LaTeX if necessary).

Comment: Are http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67446/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/ relevant?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hyperlinks in pdfs exported from org documents are generated by the LaTeX [hyperref](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/) package. This package is included by default, and options can be set in the customize interface for `org-latex-default-packages-alist`.

For example, adding the option `colorlinks=true` to the entry for hyperref will switch from boxed links to coloured links. There are quite a few options you can set, listed in the [hyperref manual](https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-90003.5).

Comment: This is great! Thank you, that helped immensely.

Answer (score 18):

While the previous answers are helpful, I'll add a bit more of an explicit recipe for Org mode.

By default, Org mode adds a rather unhelpful `hypersetup` section.  You can prevent this addition by adding the following line  to your `.emacs` file:

```
(customize-set-value 'org-latex-with-hyperref nil)
```

In addition, if you want to pass any options to `hyperref` or `url` (which is loaded automically by `hyperref`), then you can use a command of the form (notice the escaped backslash):

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-default-packages-alist "\\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}")
```

This particular command directs the `url` package to break long URLs at the end of the page over hyphens.

Then, in the Org document itself, we can add the following lines:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \hypersetup{linktoc = all, colorlinks = true, urlcolor = DodgerBlue4, citecolor = PaleGreen1, linkcolor = black}
```

The first line adds the `xcolor` package with X11 color names, and the second line specifies several options for the `hyperref` package, with the relevant option for this question being `colorlinks = true`.

See the *Package Options* section of the [hyperref documentation](ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), and the *Colors By Name* section of the [xcolor documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) for more information on the available `hyperref` settings and X11 color names, respectively.

Comment: you can simply use colors like `blue` and `green` and omit the xcolor statement, which created conflicts in my case - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperref,x11names}{xcolor}
\definecolor{electricblue}{HTML}{05ADF3}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,linktocpage,xetex]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=electricblue,filecolor=electricblue,linkcolor=electricblue,urlcolor=electricblue}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old and the existing answers are already great. But in case anyone is searching for this and needed a bit more control, here's how to change the `hyperref` template.

```
(customize-set-value 'org-latex-hyperref-template "
\\hypersetup{\n pdfauthor={%a},\n pdftitle={%t},\n pdfkeywords={%k},
 pdfsubject={%d},\n pdfcreator={%c},\n pdflang={%L},\n colorlinks=true}\n")
```

The format elements, as found in `ox-latex.el`:

```
  %a for AUTHOR keyword
  %t for TITLE keyword
  %s for SUBTITLE keyword
  %k for KEYWORDS line
  %d for DESCRIPTION line
  %c for CREATOR line
  %l for Language keyword
  %L for capitalized language keyword
  %D for DATE keyword
```